# Why do all the Windows Desktop Gadgets tell me my 4 core processor has 8 cores?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, desktop-gadget

Why do all the Windows 7 Desktop Gadgets tell me my 4 core processor has 8 cores? I have an Intel i7 870 with 4 cores. Yet every gadget I try tells me I have 8. Whats up?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your processor has [HyperThreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperThreading), giving it two *virtual/logical* cores per *physical* core.

Comment: 3 answers less than 32 seconds apart, has to be a record.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like your processor is  hyper threaded which means each core will have two threads, Windows will see these threads (logical cores) as additional cores.

Answer (score 5):

This is most probably because the i7 870 has hyperthreading (~2 hardware threads by core), my Core i5 760 shows only 4.
[For each processor core that is physically present, the operating system addresses two virtual processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the applications are detecting what is called Hyperthreading.  This feature effectively allows a single core to behave as two cores.  See the wikipedia article if you want to know more.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading